# How first EOS account was created?

Tags: accounts, account-creation

As far as I understand you can easily create new account if you have another account with EOS tokens on it.

Also there is a lot of online services that will help you to create first account for some fee. And they use their EOS account to do this.

But how first account was created without using existed EOS account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an EOS blockchain is created, it will implicitly create an account (called `eosio`).  This is a privileged account that can be used to setup and configure the blockchain, as well as create new accounts.  In the case of the main net, part of the launch process was to use this account to create the accounts for everyone who has purchased EOS tokens in the token sale.

Answer (score 1):

The very first batch of EOS accounts was created by the system account from the ERC20 EOS Token snapshot during the mainnet launch.

The mainnet launch process is like this:
https://medium.com/eos-new-york/eos-mainnet-launch-the-order-of-events-ed89a816beb8